# dropDownList is not fully populated

Tags: yii, yii2

In the view I have a such code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Language')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Doodles::getLanguages(), "Language", "language"), ['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Choose language'])->label('Language') ?>
```

In the `Doodles::getLanguages` method

```
return Doodles::findBySql('select distinct language from doodles')->asArray()->all();
```

And `getLanguages` method returns

array (size=2)

> 0 => 
>       array (size=1)
>         'language' => string 'rus' (length=3)   1 => 
>       array (size=1)
>         'language' => string 'en' (length=2)

In result page I got a select with not filled value attributes and with only one option instead two

```
<select id="utdoodles-language" class="form-control" name="UtDoodles[Language]">
<option value="">Choose language</option>
<option value="" selected="">en</option>
</select>
```

Addition:

Doodles::getLanguages method return an array:

> ```
> array (size=2)
>   0 => 
>     array (size=1)
>       'language' => string 'rus' (length=3)
>   1 => 
>     array (size=1)
>       'language' => string 'en' (length=2)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Doodles::getLanguages` method change as below :

```
return Doodles::find()->select('language')->distinct()->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: It's looks better, but gives the same result. Only `en` language in options and empty value.

Comment: I'm added this array in the bottom of my question above.

Comment: what are you storing in 'langauge' attribute in doodle table. bcs you are getting array inside array

Comment: In `Language` attribute  in the table i'm storing values `rus` and `en` with type `char(3)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145190/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-evgeny-s).